# I cant get wifi on my Mac

Tags: wireless, macbook

WiFi fails on my Mac. I did `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` and got **14e4:43a0** which tells me I have a BCM4360 WiFi module.

Every body direct me too this link but i tried. Its not working??
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: When you say 'not working' that doesn't give us any information to help you solve this. Instead, highlight and copy the result you see on the screen, click [edit], tell us exactly what you did (what commands you typed or clicked on), and paste into the question the result you see, like in the revision above. Also please tell us which version of Linux you installed and its release number. Please don't use Add Comment because it loses any formatting the original result had.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 I cant get wifi on my Mac? Pls help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206967/18-04-i-cant-get-wifi-on-my-mac-pls-help)

Answer (score -1):

The Mac uses Broadcom WiFi chips. Many distros do not support it. You need to buy an inexpensive WiFi adapter from Amazon. I think the thing is branded Edimax. Then you will have WiFi and some distros will get the driver for it. I had the same problem. After the driver is installed, you can remove the adapter for future use.

Comment: This adapter is supported.